# State of Fn-Key under Linux

Tags: linux, keyboard, fn-key

Can anyone please tell me how to read the current state of the Fn-key in Linux? Is the current state of my keyboard in "Fn" mode or "normal" mode?
I know that I can find out by pressing the keys, but I rather know before I try out.

I just can't find any device or `/proc` or mapping or whatever, where I can find out if pressing <kbd>Fn</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd> produces a "sound off" (configured in my case) or triggers the F1-action bound on the <kbd>F1</kbd> key.

Comment: What is your computer model?

Comment: Different models. DELL, HP, Noname...

Comment: What type of motherboard do you have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to do that on most common hardware, because the [<kbd>Fn</kbd> key is completely unknown to the outside world except the keyboard controller](https://superuser.com/a/786076/241386) and doesn't generate any scan code when pressing. Only when you hold it down in conjunction with another key then the keyboard controller will send the final scan code to the OS

- [Finding the scan code of FN Key](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24423724/995714)
- [Can I configure my windows key to act like a fn key?](https://superuser.com/q/1042896/241386)
- [Remap FN to another key](https://superuser.com/q/65/241386)

There are some platforms where you can capture the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key status such as macOS or some custom boards. Everything is different on a Mac, even [the <kbd>Power</kbd> button generates a scan code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3202629/995714#comment66180537_16125341) on it. If you aren't on such platforms, you're out of luck

But if you just want to get the <kbd>function keys</kbd> without pressing <kbd>Fn</kbd> then simply go into BIOS setup and change the setting to invert <kbd>Fn</kbd> behavior, most have that option along with the config to swap <kbd>Fn</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> keys. If there's no such option then you need to update the BIOS. You can also use the <kbd>Fn-lock</kbd> key on your keyboard if it's available

If there's a secondary option on <kbd>F1</kbd> then you can also remap that combo to your desired action, for example if <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> produces the <kbd>Volume down</kbd> key then remap <kbd>Volume down</kbd> to the "sound off" action you want

Answer (score 2):

You generally can't. The <kbd>Fn</kbd> key works entirely in hardware, unlike modifier keys like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>. You can find more information on the [`Fn` Key wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fn_key).

Comment: Do you know if that is documented somewhere?

Comment: Mostly but not entirely true - depends on the computer model.

Comment: ...where can I find more documentation on this?

Comment: You can find more information on the Fn Key wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fn_key). This page also contains a number of references to other websites. And yes, harrymc is correct there are exceptions, most notably Mac computers (they CAN remap fn) and some pc models use ACPI calls for the Fn key. However, for the vast majority of the time, no remapping of the Fn key is possible.

Comment: Please put this in the answer. That was what I was looking for. (Wiki did not cross my mind.) Thanks.

Comment: but why macbook can define Fn key using karabiner elements?